# How can I make my Code work on Larger Inputs

Tags: c, function, loops, structure, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the hacker rank question "Small triangle, Large triangle"
I have to arrange triangle by increasing order of area
the code I wrote  is working fine on smaller input given by me but fails on the larger inputs, after taking inputs I just get terminated
eg,
working on input
3
7 24 25
5 12 13
3 4 5

not working when
10
67 67 19
3 57 55
33 33 49
61 58 59
23 43 35
48 42 45
23 12 27
41 34 22
26 49 35
63 46 45
unable to understand why!! Thank YOU!! in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle *tr, int n)
{
    int *p = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *middle = (int*)malloc((3*n)*sizeof(int));
    // doing sum of side of triangle
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c;
    }
    // arranging sum in increasing order
    // as more the sum of a+b+c more its area in herons formula
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (p[i] < p[j])
            {
                int temp;
                temp = p[i];
                p[i] = p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    int num = 0;
    // storing sides in increasing order in middle
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (p[i] == tr[j].a + tr[j].b + tr[j].c)
            {
                middle[num] = tr[j].a;
                num++;
                middle[num] = tr[j].b;
                num++;
                middle[num] = tr[j].c;
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
    num=0;
    // copying increassed order in tr poiinter in question
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        tr[i].a = middle[num];
        num++;
        tr[i].b = middle[num];
        num++;
        tr[i].c = middle[num];
        num++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this plain c code question tagged [tag:c++]? Don't spam irrelevant tags please!

Comment: You are sorting by a+b+c, but that's not the same as sorting by area.

Comment: Consider triangles with sides `3 3 3` & `1 4 4`; which one has more area?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of strange that your function is called `sort_by_area` but it doesn't seem to calculate any area. Instead it seems to calculate the perimeter of the triangles.

Anyway... there is a bug here. (*note: There may be other bugs but to start with you need to fix this*)

```
int *middle = (int*)malloc((3*n)*sizeof(int));

...
...

int num = 0;
// storing sides in increasing order in middle
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (p[i] == tr[j].a + tr[j].b + tr[j].c)
        {
            middle[num] = tr[j].a;
            num++;
            middle[num] = tr[j].b;
            num++;
            middle[num] = tr[j].c;
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

You have two nested loops going from 0 to n. When the `if` statement is true, you increment `num` 3 times.

So in case `p[i] == tr[j].a + tr[j].b + tr[j].c` is always true (which is possible), you end up with `num` being equal to `3*n*n`.

And you use `num` as index into `middle` but `middle` is only allocated to hold `3*n` integers.

So you are writing outside the allocated area. That's undefined behavior.

**BTW**

When sorting arrays in C you should nearly always use `qsort`